# How to pass the youtube video URL to a new activity in android Studios?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, youtube, youtube-api

I have 2 activities one shows the list of videos and the other activity displays the videos using YoutubePlayerView.I use an on click button when pressed open a new activity with the youtubeplayerview.Now what i wanted is not open a new activity always for a new video insted i want to pass the youtube video as an argument so that it dosn't require many activities,just uses a single activity to display all the videos.My code is as shown below.

1. ONclick new activity using an intent.

   ```
    public void videoTitaniumOnClick(View view){
           Intent i=new Intent(this,videoGenerator.class);
           startActivity(i);

       }
   ```
2. Youtube video class Code.

   ```
   public class videoGenerator extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements OnInitializedListener {
      public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
      public static final String VideoTitanium = "ySQoAiWPXHE";
      @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
       {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
           return true;
       }


      @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_generator);

           /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
           YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)         findViewById(R.id.Youtube);
           youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
       }

      @Override
       public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

           /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
           /** Start buffering **/
           if (!wasRestored) {
               player.cueVideo(VideoTitanium);
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

           Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize Your Video.Check if you have a proper internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
   }
   ```

   Sorry if anything was wrong in the indentation.Expect the answer to be a bit clear as i am new to java and android,
   Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [intent.putExtra(key, value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

This method is overloaded and takes various types as second argument: int, byte, String, various arrays..

**So your method will be:**

```
 public void videoTitaniumOnClick(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,videoGenerator.class);
        i.putExtra("url_key", url); 
        startActivity(i);
 }
```

store the address of the youtube video which you want to pass to your another activity on click of the button and then use `putExtra() method` to pass data as I shown above.

**To get the URL on which activity you want to use URL:**

```
String url= getIntent().getStringExtra("url_key");
```

Comment: Thankyou Faisal Shaikh it's almost working but for the url it is showing as "cannot resolve symbol url" Do i need to also declare and initialise it in this class..

Comment: it is like:
`i.putExtra("url_key", "www.youtube.com/v=454erws"); `

store the address of the youtube video in the url variable.

Comment: Thanks bro i got it with your help.As i am new to java the thing i was doing wrong was initialising the String url of the second activity in main  class scope and insted i initialised it in the onInitializationSuccess method and it is working fine now..Thank you a lot..